# Неправильный тип параметров подпрограммы

Tags: pascal

Помогите,пожалуйста, исправить ошибку.
Неправильный тип параметров подпрограммы

```
const n=5;
type
TElem=integer;
arr=array[1..n]of integer;
var
mas:arr;
begin
vvod(mas, n); // Неправильный тип параметров подпрограммы

procedure vvod(var mas:arr;n:integer);
var i:integer;
begin
write('Введите последовательность');
writeln();
for i:=1 to n do
read(mas[i]);
writeln();
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код в принципе не должен компилироваться - `vvod` используется до его объявления. Вот рабочий вариант:

```
const n=5;
type
    TElem=integer;
    arr=array[1..n]of integer;

    procedure vvod(var mas:arr;n:integer);
var i:integer;
begin
    write('Введите последовательность');
    writeln();
    for i:=1 to n do
        read(mas[i]);
    writeln();
end;

var
    mas:arr;

begin
    vvod(mas, n);
    writeln('Hello, world!');
end.
```

по крайней мере он работает в [онлайновом компиляторе](http://goo.gl/dCmXrE).